# How can I resolve the error of 'serializing' from getServerSideProps in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I just changed the server from `const server = "https://backend.yourguide.pk"` to `const server = "https://stage.yourguide.pk"`, and now this error is shown. How to resolve it?

getServerSideProps's code:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  let experience = [];
  const server = 'stage.yourguide.pk';
  try {
    const data = await fetch(
      `${server}/api/user/getallexperience?title=${context.params.experiencesTitle}`,
      {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      }
    );
    experience = await data.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error is ', error);
  }

  return {
    props: {
      title: context.params.experiencesTitle,
      experience: experience.results,
    },
  };
}
```

> error - SerializableError: Error serializing `.experiences` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/".
> Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.

[image]

Comment: Kindly check the error from the image

Comment: Share your getServerSideProps code and the response type you are getting from the API

Comment: @AnuragTripathi this is response code
const server = "https://stage.yourguide.pk";

export const getExpereiece = async (username) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `${server}/api/user/getallexperience?name=${username}`,
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        mode: "cors",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  );
  const json = await response.json();
  return json.results;
};

Comment: export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  let experience = [];
  const server = "https://stage.yourguide.pk";
  try { const data = await fetch(
      `${server}/api/user/getallexperience?title=${context.params.experiencesTitle}`,
      { method: "GET",
        headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
    experience = await data.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error is ", error);
  }
  return {
    props: {
      title: context.params.experiencesTitle,
      experience: experience.results,
    },
    
  };
}

Comment: @AnuragTripathi kindly let me know how to resolve it

Comment: seems like the problem is in the response, Have you tried logging it? Serializing error comes when the data is undefined and you're trying to access a nested field, Or data is not properly converted into JSON

Comment: @AfaqKhan Try with `const server = 'https://stage.yourguide.pk';`. If this doesn't work, can you post the result of `console.log(data)` after the `fetch` call and the `/api/user/getallexperience` end-point code from your server?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `experience` is being set to `undefined`, and `undefined` is not a valid JSON value. This can be addressed with the help of a check, like so:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  let experience;
  const server = "stage.yourguide.pk";
  try {
    const data = await fetch(
      `${server}/api/user/getallexperience?title=${context.params?.experiencesTitle}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      }
    );
    experience = await data.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error is ", error);
  }

  return {
    props: {
      title: context.params?.experiencesTitle || null,
      experience: experience?.results || null,
    },
  };
}
```

Now, why you are getting `undefined`? Well, this can be because you are not using the correct endpoint, or path, or not giving the correct params, etc. Also, your error is saying `.experiences` while you have `.experience`.

Make sure you are not making any typos.